# HTML and PHP link

Tags: php, html

This code give me a list of the array and all of it's elements.. How can I place a link in every one of them redirecting to it's specific page?
Thanks

```
 <td bgcolor="<?echo $cor2;?>" align="center" class="dados">
<?
    for($i=0;$i<$num_lines;$i++)
    {
      echo $maquinas_monitorizadas[$i]->name."<br>";
    }
?>
     </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

link? do you mean

```
for($i=0;$i<$num_lines;$i++)
{
  echo '<a href="'.$maquinas_monitorizadas[$i]->name.'">'.$maquinas_monitorizadas[$i]->name.'</a><br />';
}
```

Comment: why? op was asking about links, so maybe this can help him.